# HTTP GET in async task does not work

Tags: android, apache-httpclient-4.x

I get a response from a HTTPPOST, take a substring from it which is URL and then do a HTTPGET on it, I am unable to get any response. Any inputs on what the issue could be?

```
 String pkmspogout1 = result.substring(result.indexOf(",")+1,result.length());
                        Log.i("Lpkmspogout1 ", pkmspogout1);


                    HttpClient httpclient4 = new DefaultHttpClient();

                    HttpResponse logoutresponse  ;
                    try {
                        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(pkmspogout1);

                        logoutresponse = httpclient4.execute(httpget);
                        BufferedReader in2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(logoutresponse.getEntity().getContent()));

                        StringBuffer sb2 = new StringBuffer("");

                        String line2 = "";
                        String NL2 = System.getProperty("line.separator");
                         while ((line2 = in2.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb2.append(line + NL2);

                        }
                        in2.close();


                        String pkmslogout5 = sb2.toString();
                        Log.i("logoutresponse from pkms", pkmslogout5+"");
                    } catch (Exception e) {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working finally, Phew !I tried (pkmspogout1.trim()) and it worked ! (spaces before and after the URL were the issue).

Comment: Good to know, I assumed it was something simple with the url when the encoder failed. I was going to suggest trim, but didn't think it was the issue. It is good to know to suggest it in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Is **pkmspogout1** a correct url?
Also you should make sure to do the following to see any errors:

```
catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

Try encoding the url as follows:

```
String[] url = pkmspogout1.split("com"); //Or whatever is the last part of the main url. 
                         //The letter "." means any character btw as it is a regular expression.
String finalUrl = url[0];
for(int i=0; i<url.length; i++){
     finalUrl += URLEncoder.encode(url[i],"UTF-8");
}
```

Slightly crude to be honest.... Why when forming on server side would be better to encode it then.

You could just try:

```
pkmspogout1 = pkmspogout1.replace("http://","");
pkmspogout1 = URLEncoder.encode(pkmspogout1);
pkmspogout1 = "http://"+pkmspogout1;
```

See if it is only the "http://" that is ruining your url. I still assume that it is the url that is the issue more than anything else as you told me hardcoded it works fine.

Comment: yes, when i log pkmspogout1 it is a valid url (i checked on the browser too)

Comment: Perhaps try System.out.println(line); or Log.i(line); where you are appending to check if your receiving data.

Comment: Btw, you should also make sure logoutresponse!=null.

Comment: I get "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path" , that is weird ( I am unable to share the URL for certain reasonsO

Comment: Well, I can't help you too much more than.... Presumably the url you are getting back clearly has an illegal character. If you don't see any... the best bet would be to use pkmspogout1= URLEncoder.encode(pkmspogout1, "UTF-8"); Otherwise my guess is that the url has bad characters....

Comment: when i hardcode the URL, HTTPGET response works, but when i use pkmslogout1 , it doesn't .

Comment: I used the encoder, I get 09-30 22:32:15.545: W/System.err(467): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters.
09-30 22:32:15.545: W/System.err(467):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.determineRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:572)
09-30 22:32:15.545: W/System.err(467):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:292)

Comment: This might be turning into a new question to be posted, but my guess is that you are encoding the "http://" and maybe even other characters that shouldn't be encoded. Print out the encoded string and you will see it looks a little too weird. It will probably be easier when forming the url (whatever service from the Http Post) to make sure it is properly encoded. If not you will need to manually remove the main url, urlEncode the rest, and then prepend the url again. See my new edit.

Comment: it is working finally ! phew...i tried (pkmspogout1.trim()) and it worked ! (spaces before and after the URL were the issue). I have upvoted your answer for all your inputs :) . Cheers.